# Exception occurred during store operation: Staging of a component file (Office.dll) did not succeed

Tags: c#, exception, vsto, clickonce

When we deployed the recent build of our ClickOnce product, we get the following error:

```
APPLICATION SUMMARY
* Installable application.
* Trust url parameter is set.
   ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of https://install.dev.sl.bta.cc/PA/Assette%20Presentations.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Exception occurred during store operation.
    + Value does not fall within the expected range.
   COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
* Transaction at [9/17/2011 9:39:06 AM]
    - Staging of a component file (Office.dll) did not succeed.
    - Staging of a component (dev.Appender.dll.genman) did not succeed.
    - Staging of a component file (dev.Appender.dll) did not succeed.
```

There has been nothing changed except few references. Any idea why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason of this is that the some files of the application is being opened or running during the the setup of the click once package. Make sure all the files of the application are closed

Answer (score 0):

Virus scanner was the cause of this for me. After uninstalling AVG (no luck with temporarily disabling it) installation went fine.